# Problem getting data with WooCommerce/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Usign WooCommerce for Wordpress, I'm trying to get 'order items meta data'. This is my code:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order_items = $order->get_items();
$text = "";
$text .= $order_id;
foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $item_data) {
    $item_date = $order->wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id, 'luxvila_order', true);
    $text .= "\ndate:".$item_date."\n";
}
file_put_contents("b.txt", $text);
```

My problem is that `get_items()` does not seem to be working properly and the result is the content of `b.txt` is only the `order_id`.

Comment: declared a $text blank first ?

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar I did and updated my question but the problem is still there.

Comment: I can not find the `wc_get_order_item_meta` method in the `WC_Order` class. Does it exist?

Comment: @Refilon [this is the doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html)

Comment: Could you please provide here var_dump($order_items);

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are trying to access the `wc_get_order_item_meta` from the `WC_Order` class. But there is no function in that class with that name.
I googled the function name, and found that this function should be called not from the `WC_Order` class, but directly.

Try this;

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order_items = $order->get_items();
$text = "";
$text .= $order_id;
foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $item_data) {
    $item_date = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id, 'luxvila_order', true);
    $text .= "\ndate:".$item_date."\n";
}
file_put_contents("b.txt", $text);
```

Comment: thank you but still not working I think the problem is from get_items() function! it returns zero items!!

Comment: @Amir what is in the `$order_id`??